# How do libatlas3, liblapacke, and libopenblas0 interact in Focal?

Tags: package-management, libraries, shared-library, update-alternatives, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to figure out the interaction between the following library packages:

- libatlas3-base
- liblapacke
- OpenBLAS

  - libopenblas0-openmp
  - libopenblas0-pthread
  - libopenblas0-serial

It looks like the OpenBLAS packages can only be used one at a time because they are in different subdirs shown here.  How do I select the active one?

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-openmp/libopenblas.so.0
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblas.so.0
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-serial/libopenblas.so.0

Once I've selected the active OpenBLAS implementation, will libatlas3 or liblapacke use the active implementation?  How can you tell what they are using?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69276806/14055985